# How do you avoid an ArrayList object from being modified, i.e. avoid adding and deleting its content?

Tags: java, arraylist

How do you avoid an ArrayList object in (Java) from being modified, i.e. avoid adding and deleting its content

Answer (score 4):

By creating an unmodifiable list out of it:

```
List<Object> dontModify = Collections.unmodifiableList(originalList);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't give the `ArrayList` to anything you don't trust - instead, you use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to create an immutable wrapper around the existing list, and give untrusted code that instead.

Note that this only gives a *wrapper* around the existing list - anything with access to the original list can still modify it. If you want to create a completely immutable list, you can either use a dedicated class (e.g. [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) or create a copy of the original list, wrap that copy using `Collections.unmodifiableList`, and throw away the reference to the mutable list (so only the immutable wrapper knows about it).

Comment: Yes, ImmutableList is more immutable than Collections.unmodifiableList().

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu: But not more immutable than `unmodifiableList` wrapping a list which nothing else knows about any more, presumably. That's a simple approach if the OP wants to avoid taking a dependency on Guava.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the exact requirements:

- `Collections.unmodifiableList(arrayList)` gives you an unmodifiable view of the original list - that's probably what you need
- guava's [`ImmutableList`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html) makes a list that is immutable (and not a view) (you'd have to copy the `ArrayList` elements to the immutable list)